# Excel VBA - Manipulate Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, vba

I have researched stackoverflow and other sources for many weeks for an answer to this question but have not been able to uncover an answer.  I appreciate that there may be other posts that indirectly deal with the topic, but nothing seems to address the requirements of the specific example I have in mind, so I'm taking the plunge and posting.  My request:

On the website www.4-traders.com there's an input box located at the top center of the page for entering a company name or stock ticker symbol.  The page contains code that calls a javascript function as one types into the input box.  The javascript searches a database for the best matches to the text being input, and the output of the javascript function is presented as a floating list box that one can select from.  The code for this component of the page is as follows:

```html
<td class="recherche_bl">
          <input type="hidden" name="lien" value="recherche">
          <input onblur="GlobalSearch.ACblur();" onkeyup="GlobalSearch.ACkeyUp(event)" onkeydown="return GlobalSearch.ACkeyDown(event);" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="mots" id="autocomplete" class="inputrecherche" value="Symbol or Keyword(s)" onclick="document.recherche_menu.mots.value='';GlobalSearch.LoadHisto()">
          <input type="image" src="/images/loupe_recherche.png" class="htZo" align="absmiddle" onclick="document.getElementById('noredirect').value='1'">
          <input type="hidden" name="RewriteLast" value="zbat">
          <input type="hidden" id="noredirect" name="noredirect" value="0">
          <input type="hidden" id="type_recherche" name="type_recherche" value="0">      
</td>
```

GlobalSearch is the javascript function I'm interested in.  I'd like to get Excel VBA to somehow select from the output of the GlobalSearch function after a value is input into the form.  I currently have to use sendkeys to accomplish this, which as everyone knows has a number of drawbacks and requires that an Internet Explorer windows is open at the time.  Here is the code I'm currently using for this piece:

1. The value of Ticker is set before this part of the code.
2. .document refers to an Internetexplorer.Application object I have created earlier on in the code.
3. PauseTime is a procedure used to delay the execution of code.
4. The two lines involving sending a 'space' and 'backspace' key are used to get the javascript to run (it doesn't seem to run without some manual user input).  Once the javascript runs I want the procedure to select the first instance in the list box, so I send a 'down' key and then an 'enter' key.

```html
.document.recherche_menu.mots.Focus
.document.forms("recherche_menu")("mots").Value = Ticker
PauseTime (2)
Application.SendKeys (" ")
Application.SendKeys ("{BS}")
PauseTime (2)
Application.SendKeys ("{DOWN}")
Application.SendKeys ("~")
```

I would really appreciate some help to figure this out.  I think the real issue is that I don't have a deep enough understanding of javascript to code what I need to into Excel VBA.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Constantine